# Hiding 'Excel options' and 'Exit Excel' using VSTO

Tags: vsto, excel-2007

I would like to hide the default 'Excel options' and 'Exit Excel' buttons in the Office button in Excel 2007.

I am using VSTO for programming functionality for my projects. Is there any pre-render event I can override where I can access the OfficeMenu items collections and set a Visible=false property there?

Customizing the Ribbon using xml only allows me to disable the buttons.

Is it possible to hide them or is this not allowed?

Thank you in advance.